# Angular - DI dependency injection the connection between different Modules and service\directive from another module

Tags: angularjs

If I need a to use a factory from another module do I need to add first the DI of the module to my current module and after that add the DI of the factory to the current factory? Or can I just add the factory itself (without its module)?

So if above its true the only use of Di in modules is for that use... or am i missing something else?

Answer (score 0):

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.service('myService', function() {
  // do some stuff
});
myApp.controller('otherCtrl', function($scope, myService) {
  // do some stuff
});
```

inject **myApp** module into **otherApp** module and use service **myService**:

```
var otherApp = angular.module('otherApp', ['myApp']);
otherApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, myService) {
    $scope.myService = myService; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

declare modules with dependecies.

```
var baseApp = angular.module("ERMSApp", ['ngSanitize', 'ngRoute', 'ngTable']);

var baseApp1 = angular.module("ERMSApp1", ['ERMSApp', 'ngSanitize', 'ngRoute', 'ngTable']);
```

declaring service.

```
baseApp.factory("getEmployeesService", function ($http) {
var promise;
var getEmployeesService = {
    getEmployees: function () {
        if (!promise) {
            var promise = $http.get("/Timesheet/GetEmployees").then(function (result) {
                return result;
            });
        }
        return promise;
    }
}
return getEmployeesService;
```

});

using service in another module

```
baseApp1.controller("leaveOnBehalfCtrl", function ($scope, $http, $filter, $sce, ngTableParams, $compile, getEmployeesService) {
getEmployeesService.getEmployees().then(function (data) {
    $scope.employees = data.data;
})
```

});